# How to take screenshot of a page which is larger than the screen i.e. webpage?

Tags: 14.04

I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I used Ubuntu screenshot application in my computer. But it can maximum take a screenshot of whole screen.

What can I do if I want to take screenshot of a page which is larger than the screen i.e. webpage?

Comment: For webpage you must install addon/extension on your browser

Comment: You may be interested on a application named `shutter`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to indicate WHERE the answer to a duplicate question is?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a photo of the site in its default state, you can do that from the command line using `gnome-web-photo` without even visiting the site in your browser.
Or if you already use the advanced screenshot tool `shutter`, the command will automatically be integrated there as well.

#### Installation:

You need the package `gnome-web-photo` installed. Get it with the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-web-photo
```

#### Help overview:

Here are the options that `gnome-web-photo` supports:

```
$ gnome-web-photo --help
Usage:
  gnome-web-photo [OPTION...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                 Show help options
  --help-all                 Show all help options
  --help-gtk                 Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -m, --mode                 Operation mode [photo|thumbnail|print]
  -c, --user-css=CSSFILE     User style sheet to use for the page (default: /usr/share/gnome-web-photo/style.css)
  -d, --delay=D              Delay in seconds to wait after page is loaded, or 0 to disable delay (default: 0)
  -t, --timeout=T            Timeout in seconds to wait to load the page, or 0 to disable timeout (default: 60)
  -f, --force                Force output when timeout expires, even if the page is not fully loaded
  -w, --width=W              Desired width of the web page (default: 1024)
  -s, --thumbnail-size=S     Thumbnail size (default: 256)
  -p, --printer=PRINTER      Print page on PRINTER (default: none, save as PDF)
  --print-background         Print background images and colours (default: false)
  --disable-plugins          Disable embedded plugins in the rendering engine (default: enable plugins)
  --file                     Argument is a file and not a URI
  --display=DISPLAY          X display to use
```

#### Usage examples:

To capture e.g. http://askubuntu.com as PNG image, you could type the following command:

```
gnome-web-photo "http://askubuntu.com" askubuntu.png
```

Here is the created PNG image: [external link to image on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d390y.png)

If you want a PDF like the print preview you would get from your browser instead of a PNG, use `gnome-web-print`. It's a shortcut for `gnome-web-photo --mode=print`:

```
gnome-web-print "http://askubuntu.com" askubuntu.pdf
```

It also supports creation of a small thumbnail image in PNG format. `gnome-web-thumbnail` is again a shortcut for `gnome-web-photo --mode=thumbnail`:

```
gnome-web-print "http://askubuntu.com" askubuntu.pdf
```

#### Additional notes:

Don't forget the `http://` or `https://` protocol! Otherwise the command may crash and you'd have to abort it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Note also that it also prints some normally irrelevant output, e.g. the Java version it uses... Just ignore that as long as there are no error messages...

Answer (score 0):

I use Awesome Screenshot add on in Firefox. You can get similar extension in chrome also. It enables you to capture both selected part or the whole page.